# Webview Javascript chamando método java - android

Tags: javascript, java, android

Tenho um app webview que chama uma index.html :

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");
```

nessa index tenho um javascript que acessa uma função java para verificar se existe conexão, se o retorno for true ele envia para meu site:

```
function connection(){
   return android.CheckConnection();
}
if(!connection()){
   alert('sem conexão');
}else{
   window.location.href = 'http://meusite.com';
}
```

função java acessada pelo javascript

```
@JavascriptInterface
public boolean CheckConnection(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Quando meu site é carregado, ele tenta acessar as funções do java assim como fiz com a index.html porém é retornado um erro "Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala Gustavo,

Tenta trocar essa linha:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");
```

Por essa:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
```

E fora do seu onCreate, coloca esse método:

```
/* An instance of this class will be registered as a JavaScript interface */
    class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        @JavascriptInterface
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void processHTML(String html)
        {
            // process the html as needed by the app
        }
    }
```

Abraços.

Comment: Leonardo, a minha função CheckConnection deve ficar dentro da classe MyJavaScriptInterface? fiz desta maneira e o erro persiste, mas o problema piorou porque agora o jquery do site também parou de funcionar

Comment: Qual erro que apresenta no seu LogCat? O mesmo de antes?

Comment: Descobri que rodando o app normalmente tudo está funcionando, porém este erro acontece quando o app está fechado (clear data) e ele recebe uma notificação, ao clicar na notificação ele inicia o app que após carregar a webview com jquery, o jquery executa um metodo do java e nesse momento o erro acontece, lembrando que o erro acontece somente quando inicio o app via notificação...o logcat é o mesmo sim Leonardo